# Simple object building by xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, controls

I have a simple class and I want to simply create instances of my class via xaml. But I'm still getting errors like: "'Test' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name."

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfTestApplication1
{
    public class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }

        public UserControl1()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication1">
    <local:UserControl1>
        <Setter Property="Test" Value="aaaa" />
    </local:UserControl1>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have set the `Property` on your `UserControl` is not valid. You have set the `Content` of your `UserControl` by putting `Setter` inside the nodes.

First define Test as `DependencyProperty` if you want it to be binding target and then set it directly on UserControl as

```
 <local:UserControl1 Test="aaaa"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [DependencyProperty](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html) instead of default property.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I tried it, but the same problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As @us3r said...DependencyProperty is what you are looking for.

What you have to do is:

```
// Dependency Property
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register( "Test", typeof(string),
     typeof(UserControl1 ));

// .NET Property wrapper
public string Test
{
    get { return GetValue(TestProperty ).; }
    set { SetValue(TestProperty , value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help. I tried it, but the same problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it out.
I defined the control in xaml as

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Key="xxx" Test="aaaa"/>
```

Without using setter and property statements, just by directly defining the property.
Thanks for help!